# Dotfill the left end of paragraph's first line to get right end of paragraph's last line to the margin?

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, paragraphs

In TeX or LaTeX can you dot-fill from the left end of the first line of a paragraph until the right end of the last line of the paragraph is at the right margin?

Instead of

```
word01 word02 word03 word04 word05
word06 word07 word08 word09 word10
word11 word12
```

something like

```
.....................word01 word02
word03 word04 word05 word06 word07 
word08 word09 word10 word11 word12
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\dotfill Quisque efficitur lacinia aliquet.
Quisque vitae magna vel enim laoreet molestie eu in nunc.
Ut in condimentum mi. Morbi mattis metus quis leo rhoncus
convallis. Sed ultrices dolor vehicula, mollis neque non,
hendrerit quam. Ut ut erat vitae dui blandit consequat.
Praesent euismod mauris sit amet erat feugiat ultricies
at vitae ante. Mauris vel ante porttitor, rutrum tortor
at, fringilla nulla. Morbi eget neque cursus, eleifend
libero vitae, pulvinar ipsum. Maecenas ut tellus tempus
eros venenatis aliquam.
\begingroup\parfillskip=0pt \par\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]